# Rails - I can't display locations on my users form using nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I can't display the locations that belogns to the user using nested forms.

I want to create the user and save the address, city, state, etc in location model and the name, username, email in the user model.

I have no errors on the console. But the fields (select or dropdowns, text_fields, etc) are not showing up. The database has records.

This is my user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :locations
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations   
end
```

This is my location.rb model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my user form:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
  <%= form_for(["admin", @user]) do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :username %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :password %>
    </div>

    <!-- Here is the nested form -->

    <%= f.fields_for :locations do |location| %>
      <%= location.label :country %>
      <%= location.select :country%>

      <%= location.label :state %>
      <%= location.text_field :state%>

    <% end %>

    <div class="actions form-group">
      <%= f.submit class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Does your @user object has an location already? If not, you need to build one to server as the place holder for the first location (when creating).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your view:

```
<% f.object.locations.build if f.object.locations.empty? %>
<%= f.fields_for :locations do |location| %>
....
```

You can also add this logic in controller, but I would add it to the view. Why? Because if you would want to reuse this form in another controller, you will have to duplicate your code.

And if you want to add more than one location in the future, I would suggest you to watch these two railscats:

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2
```