# Nested form fields not showing in polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

Hi I have a `polymorphic` association with for a `Document` model for storing document uploads. I'm trying to submit the document attributes as a nested attribute via the associated model.

However, when I load the form, the nested field does not show. What am I missing?

Schema:

```
  create_table "documents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.json     "links"
    t.integer  "linkable_id"
    t.string   "linkable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "documents", ["linkable_type", "linkable_id"], name: "index_documents_on_linkable_type_and_linkable_id", using: :btree
```

Models:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

  mount_uploaders :links, DocUploader
end



class CustomerPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, as: :linkable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
end
```

Controller:

```
class CustomerPlanController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @customer_plan = current_company.customer_plans.build
  end

  def create
    @customer_plan = current_company.customer_plans.build(customer_plan_params)

    if @customer_plan.save
      redirect_to @customer_plan, notice: 'Customer plan was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def cusomter_plan_params
      params.require(:cusomter_plan_params).permit(:date, :name, :plan_type, 
        documents_attributes: [:id, links: []])
    end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @stock_plan, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :date %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :plan_type %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :documents do |d| %>
      <p><b>Upload here:</b></p>
      <%= d.file_field :links, multiple: true %>
      <br>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i think def new missing  build "1.times { @customer_plan.documents.build } "

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. Seems like a silly oversight. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063470/rails-i-cant-display-locations-on-my-users-form-using-nested-forms/38063760#38063760. It is very similar and has some more explanations about design decisions.